# Строка загрузки

Tags: gui, многопоточность, java

Доброго времени суток!
Есть приложение которое при загрузке выполняет несколько запросов к БД. Пока они выполняются само приложение не запускается, так вот во время выполнения этих запросов нужно сделать окошко типа -"Подождите идет загрузка" с бегущей строкой. 
 Проблема в том что окошко запускается но оно просто с белым экраном и нет бегущей строки!!  Помогите, пожалуйста, кто знает в чем причина.

```
package com.db.main;
import java.awt.Color;
public class window {

    private JFrame frmAgrofirm;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTable Staff;
    private JTable table_3;
    private JTable Graph;
    private JTable Depart;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    window window = new window();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public window() {

        initialize();
        load.setVisible(true);

        initWindow();

        load.setVisible(false);
        frmAgrofirm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initWindow() {

        comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(Functions.LoadWindow()));

        DefaultTableModel newModel = (DefaultTableModel) Staff
                .getModel();
        newModel.setDataVector(Functions.LoadStaff(), zagStaf);
        Staff.setModel(newModel);
        Staff.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(20);
        Staff.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(193);
        Staff.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(60);
        Staff.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(140);
        Staff.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(135);

        DefaultTableModel newModel1 = (DefaultTableModel) Depart.getModel();
        newModel1.setDataVector(Functions.LoadDepart(), zagDep);
        Depart.setModel(newModel1);
        Depart.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(20);
        Depart.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(193);
        Depart.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(160);
        Depart.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(40);

        DefaultTableModel newModel2 = (DefaultTableModel) Graph.getModel();
        newModel2.setDataVector(Functions.LoadGraph(), zagGraph);
        Graph.setModel(newModel2);
        Graph.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(20);
        Graph.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(210);
        Graph.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(60);
        Graph.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);
        Graph.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);             
    }

    JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();

    private static JFrame load = new JFrame();

    private void initialize() {
        load.setTitle("Load");
        load.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JPanel panel_6 = new JPanel();
        load.getContentPane().add(panel_6, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        panel_6.add(progressBar);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        JLabel label_5 = new JLabel("Загрузка....");
        panel_6.add(label_5);
        load.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работу с БД нужно засунуть в отдельный поток, иначе будет блокироваться обработка сообщений гуя (он не будет перерисовываться, т.к. занят общением с базой).

GUI менять можно только из того потока, в котором он создается, поэтому схема такая:
должен быть GUI-поток и поток обработки. Второй должен сигналить первому при возникновении каких-то событий: началась обработка (GUI-поток показывает окошко загрузки), обработан еще один запрос (GUI-поток увеличивает значение прогрессбара), обработка закончена (GUI-поток закрывает окошко загрузки, рисует результаты).

Гуглить: класс Thread, интерфейс Runnable, синхронизация потоков